# How do I use CODI Conversation? Specifically, how to end it?

Tags: jsf-2, myfaces, codi

Based on advice posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061709/how-do-i-use-conversationscoped) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419442/cdi-weld-how-to-handle-browser-page-refresh-after-ending-conversation/7140564#7140564), I looked into and installed [MyFaces CODI](http://myfaces.apache.org/extensions/cdi/index.html) with my application.  My biggest concern was overcoming the shortcomings of Weld's implementation of @ConversationScoped feature.  After some hiccups I got it running on my GlassFish 3.1 development platform, and I converted all my beans to use

```
import org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.scope.conversation.ConversationScoped;
```

In the end it seems like I am now not much further along than I was before.  I do not have to call the **conversation.begin()** method anymore, which is good, but the beans hang around after the browser has left the page and come back.

What I was hoping for was the functionality of JSF 2.0 @ViewScoped that works with CDI.  Once the user leaves the page, the backing bean should be discarded and re-created again if the user comes back.  Is there a way to do this with CODI?

Incidentally, the documentation says it will pick up the @ViewScoped annotations and process them properly.  I tried this and got and Weld wouldn't deploy it.

P.S. I am using myfaces-extcdi-dist-jsf20 version 0.9.5.  I tried installing the core and JSF 2 optional module akibe but it would not deploy on my GlassFish/Weld platform.   Any advice here much appreciated.

UPDATE 1:  I ended up trying the ViewAccessScope annotation supported by CODI, and that seems to do what I wanted.

Follow-up question.  The latest bundle that the maven repository that Apache maintains is 0.9.5 -- Can someone post the pom.xml segment that fetches the latest version?

Comment: Call conversation.close() before returning - ensure that you imported the correct annotation org.apache... and not javax... - see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/EXTCDI/JSF+Usage#JSFUsage-TerminatingConversations or use the ViewAccessScope instead. We are using: http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/myfaces/extensions/cdi/bundles/myfaces-extcdi-bundle-jsf20/1.0.1/myfaces-extcdi-bundle-jsf20-1.0.1.jar in Glassfish 3.1.1 without problems. myfaces-extcdi-bundle-jsf20-1.0.1.jar is the only jar you need.

Comment: @DarWhi if you post your answer as an answer I will green-check it for you.   Please see the update to my question.

Comment: The Maven config for the all in one package is documented at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/EXTCDI/Module+Overview#ModuleOverview-CODIprepackagedbundles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call conversation.close() before returning - ensure that you imported the correct annotation org.apache... and not javax... - see [Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/EXTCDI/JSF+Usage#JSFUsage-TerminatingConversations) or use the ViewAccessScope instead. We are using: [bundle](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/myfaces/extensions/cdi/bundles/myfaces-extcdi-bundle-jsf20/1.0.1/myfaces-extcdi-bundle-jsf20-1.0.1.jar) in Glassfish 3.1.1 without problems. myfaces-extcdi-bundle-jsf20-1.0.1.jar is the only jar you need. Please also note that there is no "it". With CODI you have fine-grained groupable conversations instead of the monolithic and inflexible stuff you get with standard CDI conversations.

The set-up for the latest version with a Maven build is also in the [Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/EXTCDI/Module+Overview#ModuleOverview-CODIprepackagedbundles).